# Alarm turns off when Clock App is closed

Tags: alarm, clock

When I close the Clock app the alarm no longer works. I have noticed that closing the app causes the little alarm icon to go away (indicating the alarm is no longer on). This never happened before, the alarm icon would stay on even if the app were not open.

I have cleared the clock app cache, restarted the phone, reset all settings and restarted again all to no avail.

This is on a Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra, Android 14 and it is the native Clock app that came with it.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that the alarm indeed doesn't go off? Or is the icon just going away? Have you tested with a different clock/alarm app yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried several times by setting the alarm to go off in 5 minutes, at which point the icon shows, then close the app, icon disappears, five minutes later, no alarm.
I did install a different app and it works just fine, but it is add supported and frankly it is just stupid that the native alarm app doesn't work.

Comment: That is pretty frustrating! I wouldn't imagine there's a setting to change as this couldn't really be expected to be the intended behavior of the app. Next steps I'd consider are seeing if there are updates for the app, checking for device updates, doing a factory reset (which it sounds like you may have already done), and finally - reaching out to Samsung 

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me, remove clock from the sleeping apps on the background usage menu. Open settings, battery, backgound usage limits, sleeping apps... Find clock and long press it. Remove it from the list. Now when you close the app it continues running on the background and the icon will not dissapear. Alarm will sound